# デプロイしたアプリで日本語が使えないエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws, デプロイ

タイトル通りなのですが、デプロイしたアプリをブラウザ上からデータを登録する際に日本語の入力ができなってWe're sorry, but something went wrong.のエラーページになってしまいます。英語ですと普通に登録ができます。

やったことはaws(EC2)でRDSのパラメーターグループの確認とターミナルで直接mysqlに接続して確認し訂正しました。

↓ターミナルでmysql接続した際の画面

```
| Variable_name            | Value                                     
|
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------- 
+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      
|
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      
|
| character_set_database   | utf8                                      
|
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    
|
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      
|
| character_set_server     | utf8                                      
|
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      
|
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.39.R1/share/charsets/ 
|
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: 11223344
  database: portfolio_production
  encoding: utf8

development:
  <<: *default
  database: portfolio_production

test:
  <<: *default
  database: portfolio_production

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: portfolio_production
  username: root
  password: 11223344
  host: portfolio-mysql.cxputm26p9ho.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306
```

↓日本語入力した際のエラーログ

```
     D, [2018-05-25T07:06:01.042200 #3172] DEBUG -- : [40b88ae2-9446- 
4191-95e7-a1cdb3c3ca04]   SQL (3.0ms)  INSERT INTO `categories` 
(`c_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('あ', '2018-05-25 
07:06:01', '2018-05-25 07:06:01')
D, [2018-05-25T07:06:01.045021 #3172] DEBUG -- : [40b88ae2-9446-4191- 
95e7-a1cdb3c3ca04]    (2.7ms)  ROLLBACK
I, [2018-05-25T07:06:01.045197 #3172]  INFO -- : [40b88ae2-9446-4191- 
95e7-a1cdb3c3ca04] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms 
(ActiveRecord: 12.5ms)
F, [2018-05-25T07:06:01.046044 #3172] FATAL -- : [40b88ae2-9446-4191- 
95e7-a1cdb3c3ca04]   
F, [2018-05-25T07:06:01.046087 #3172] FATAL -- : [40b88ae2-9446-4191- 
95e7-a1cdb3c3ca04] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: 
Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x81\x82' for column 'c_name' at row 1: 
INSERT INTO `categories` (`c_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES 
('あ', '2018-05-25 07:06:01', '2018-05-25 07:06:01')):
F, [2018-05-25T07:06:01.046139 #3172] FATAL -- : [40b88ae2-9446-4191- 
95e7-a1cdb3c3ca04]   
F, [2018-05-25T07:06:01.046161 #3172] FATAL -- : [40b88ae2-9446-4191- 
95e7-a1cdb3c3ca04] app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:19:in 
`block in create'
[40b88ae2-9446-4191-95e7-a1cdb3c3ca04] 
app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

schema

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c_name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

以上なのですが他にどうしたらよいのかわからず困っています。もし何かお気付きのところなどございましたら教えていただきたいです。宜しくお願いしますm(._.)m

Comment: エラーが発生しているcategoriesテーブルのスキーマ情報もいただけますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！スキーマ情報載せました！
一応あの後自己解決もできました！
ご覧いただきありがとうございました！また機会ありましたら宜しくお願いしますm(._.)m

Comment: 自己解決したのであれば、その解決内容を自己回答してください。よろしくおねがいします

Comment: 先にコメントしてから書こうと思ってましたので失礼しました。只今拙いながらも書きました。ありがとうございましたm(._.)m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決できました！！
おかしな点が見つからなかったのですが、エラーログからDB関連なのかな？と思い色々調べていたらDB全体ではなくて、テーブル指定して文字設定できるみたいなので使っているテーブル全てにutf8を当てまして、インスタンス再起動したらうまくいきました！

ターミナルでmysqlに接続してmysqlのコマンド以下入力です。

ALTER TABLE テーブル名 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8；

大文字じゃないといけないのかはわかりませんが、テーブル名のところは自分のテーブル名通り小文字で入力しました。

以上です。ありがとうございましたm(._.)m